# "He for She" or "He for Her"?

Tags: slogan, motto, nominative-vs-oblique

Of course we all know that when a personal pronoun is the object of a verb or a preposition, it must be an objective pronoun.  My question here is about the choice of a nominative pronoun in the slogan of the solidarity movement for gender equality "He for She".  It sounds ungrammatical to me and I wonder why it was preferred. Can anyone explain?

Comment: My guess would be marketing. They probably took a litmus test of the target audience and decided based on which charted better. It could also be because if you say "he for her" quickly, it sounds like *heiffer*. Conjuring the image of a cow is not a way to win supporters in a gender equality movement. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because slogans don't have to be "grammatical".

Comment: @Ian I doubt that last one. _Heifer_ has a different vowel, [ε], from _he (for)_, [i:], so they don't really sound anything like each other.

Comment: @Janus I suppose it depends on your local accent.

Comment: "No one can play better than he" is grammatically correct. Most people would expect the object pronoun "him" there, but in historical works, the subject pronoun was preferred. I'm quite eager myself to find the reason for such usage.

Comment: @AndySemyonov   ...than he does.  ("does" is implicit)

Comment: The chosen pronouns are equal?

Comment: @Centaurus Thanks for the answer. My example is not to be confused with yours now.

Comment: I can’t quite make out what you are looking for here, but you want to choose the same case for the pronoun in any event. So depending on your use, 1) *Him for Her* 2) *He for She* 3) *His for Hers* are your possibilities, of which the first is by far the most likely and least strange to the ear.  That’s because **the object form of the pronoun is the default case in English**, not the subject or possessive form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a sentence where applying grammatical rules is obligatory, but merely a title for a campaign aiming to raise awareness. Hence it is only logical to pick words that will make the title catchier and somewhat easier to pronounce.

Answer (score 2):

The "he" and "she" are being mentioned, rather than used.  The quotation is implicit: "'He' for 'She'".  Quoted forms are not subject to grammatical rules.  If they were, for instance, you might have *They said "Harry likes turtles."* getting a passive form *Harry was said "likes turtles."*

I generally see it spelled HeForShe, and if the "She" is just part of a word, that is another reason it can't be changed to "her", since parts of words are also not subject to grammatical rules.